# Javascript .val() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I enter a decimal for chance, it returns NaN for pay and profit.  Any idea why?  Also what would I need to do to round profit to the second decimal.

Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        function updateValues() {
            // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
            var chance = $('#chance').val();
            var bet = $('#bet').val();
            var pay = $('#pay').val();
            var profit = $('#profit').val();

            // Calculate the new payout.
            var remainder = 101 - chance;
            pay = Math.floor((992/(chance+0.5)) *100)/100;


            // Calculate the new profit.
            profit = bet*pay-bet;



            // Set the new input values.
            $('#chance').val(chance);
            $('#bet').val(bet);
            $('#pay').val(pay);
            $('#profit').val(profit);
        }


        $('#chance').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#bet').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#pay').keyup(updateValues);
        $('#profit').keyup(updateValues);


    });
```

Comment: `val` retrieves strings _not_ numbers. So at some point you're not using a number but a string.

Comment: What "decimal" in particular?

Comment: convert your inputs to Number cause they are strings. Ex: var chance = Number($('#chance').val()); ... do this for all of them

Comment: Could it be that your html input type=number?

Comment: @KhanhTO Math.round returns an `integer`, but OP wants to keep 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parseFloat to properly work with the values, which by default are strings:

```
var chance = parseFloat($('#pay').val());
/*same for other values*/
```

To round the profit to 2 decimals, you can use toFixed on that number, which again converts it back to a string.

```
3.123.toFixed(2) = "3.12"
```

Comment: That's making my issue worse.  It's causing multiplier to give 19.64 when it should be 1.98 which is what it was prior.  Still having a problem.

Comment: Still haven't fixed it...  Any ideas?

Comment: @Jake then something is wrong with your formula, not with the `parseFloat`.

Comment: @Jake Math.floor((992/(parseFloat("0.5")+0.5)) *100)/100 == 992 - what should be the correct solution? The formula altogether does not look very sound. Multiplying with 100 before the floor and then dividing by 100 looks somehow strange. You should always search the problem within your own code, before blaiming standard functionality to save your self from embarrassment.

Comment: I'm not afraid being embarrassed of my mistakes.  That code won't work.  I need chance+0.5 for this to work and the 992.  I put parseInt and it still returns NaN when I put 50.1 or 50.anything for chance.

Comment: @Jake `parseInt("50.anything",10)` will in every case give you `50` as result, `parseFloat("50.123anything")` will give you `50.123`. There will not be `NaN` as result except your input starts with a `non-digit` (in which case both methods will return NaN, but the same would happen without parsing the input). Please construct a small example on http://jsfiddle.net if you want to receive further help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var chance = parseFloat($("#Chance").val());
```

You can also use `toFixed` to specify the number of decimal places.

**Edit**

You need to modify `chance`:

```
chance = parseFloat(chance);
```

You can see this working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/U8bpX/

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone.  I don't even know how.  Still trying to figure this out and I'm appreciative for the help regardless if it works.

Comment: @JakeMcLaughlin - I've updated my answer and provided a JSFiddle.  It's working for me with decimal numbers.

Comment: OK so Darren I put parseFloat((chance+0.5))) but it's giving 19.8 instead of 1.98.  How to fix?

Comment: @Jake take a closer look at your formula. What is it supposed to do? Can you explain the formula for us? Perhaps we then can spot the error in there.

Comment: @Jake - can you provide me with the values for chance and bet and the desired output?

Comment: Yeah.  So I'm making a BTC gambling site and it's a 2% house edge.  So 49% bettor odds should make for a 2X payout.  You get what I'm saying?

Comment: @JakeMcLaughlin - I'm not a gambler.  Can you provide us with some examples.  I.e. if chance is 20, bet is 5.2 the output should be X.

Comment: var remainder = 100.5 - chance;
pay = Math.floor((992/(chance+0.5)) *100)/100;  This should explain where the X ( Multiplier ) comes from.  If someone wants to win 90% of the time obviously they're going to be winning more so get paid alot less + the house edge is factored in.

Comment: It's working but instead of 19.8 I need 1.98.  It seems like it's an easy fix I'm missing..

Answer (score 1):

First make use of parseFloat or (parseInt if you don't need float values).

```
 function updateValues() {

        var chance = parseFloat($('#chance').val());
        var bet = parseFloat($('#bet').val());
        var pay = parseFloat($('#pay').val());
        var profit = parseFloat($('#profit').val());

        // Calculate the new payout.
        var remainder = 101 - chance;
        pay = Math.floor((992/(chance+0.5)) *100)/100;


    }
```

> `Also what would I need to do to round profit to the second decimal.`

```
you can do this:
              profit = bet*pay-bet;
              profit = profit.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: that parseFloat is taking me two steps back.  It's screwing up the pay and profit.

Comment: have you also tried with parseInt just to confirm what is causing the problem? Please remember to put parseInt/parseFloat in all your inputs where you are using val()